# error while selecting from external table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I'm new to Oracle and trying to create a table of `catagories`. The table is created finely and altered finely:

```
CREATE TABLE CATAGORIES
( Code VARCHAR2(10) NOT NULL,
CategoryName VARCHAR2(250),
Active  VARCHAR2(1))
/
ALTER TABLE CATAGORIES ADD CONSTRAINT PK_CATAGORIES PRIMARY KEY(CODE)
/
```

But when inserting in it these errors occurred:

```
INSERT INTO CATAGORIES(Code,CategoryName,Active)
select LPAD(ROWNUM,5,'0') AS Code, Category,'Y'
from
(
SELECT count(Product),Replace(Category,'"','') as Category from TEMPDATA_EXT
Where Category!='Category'
group by Category
)



SQL> INSERT INTO CATAGORIES(Code,CategoryName,Active)
  2  select LPAD(ROWNUM,5,'0') AS Code, Category,'Y'
  3  from
  4  (
  5  SELECT count(Product),Replace(Category,'"','') as Category from TEMPDATA_EXT
  6  Where Category!='Category'
  7  group by Category
  8  )
  9  /
INSERT INTO CATAGORIES(Code,CategoryName,Active)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN callout
ORA-29400: data cartridge error
KUP-00554: error encountered while parsing access parameters
KUP-01005: syntax error: found "skip": expecting one of: "column, enclosed, (,
ltrim, lrtrim, ldrtrim, missing, notrim, optionally, rtrim, reject"
KUP-01007: at line 3 column 4
```

Comment: Most people here want formatted text, not images (or links to images.)

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do, and what the error is. Your links don't work (one of the reasons most people don't like links in questions)

Comment: Please have a look at [ask] and [mcve] before posting a question. Also, [avoid  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Is your table actually named `CATAGORIES`? Because that's not a word.  Syntactically it doesn't matter what the name is so long as it is actually that. I just find it odd that a word that's a typo is your table name. 
 `CATEGORIES` is how you actually spell the word.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates a problem with an external table.

> ORA-29913: error in executing ODCIEXTTABLEOPEN

So we can guess the `TEMPDATA_EXT` referenced in the INSERT statement is an  External Table. So the problem is not with the `CATEGORIES` table but with the table you're selecting from.

There are several things it might be:

1. There might be a problem with permissions on the OS directory or the database directory object.
2. There may be a problem with the contents of the data file you're trying to load from.

The External Table should have specified a Log file and a Bad file. These are written to the OS directory. Your first action should be to look at them. Use the [ALL_EXTERNAL_TABLES view will give you the database directory](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1057.htm#REFRN20074). To find the operating system directory you need to cross reference that with [the ALL_DIRECTORIES view](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1050.htm#i1576965).